# CSS repeat a background image after a background image finishes

Tags: css, background, background-image, repeat

I need to use a static no-repeating background image on my website,  but when the image finishes (vertically), i need to use repeatedly another image. How could this be done?

For the first image should be something like:

```
background:url(../img/header/main_bg01.jpg) no-repeat top center;
```

But for the second one, vertically after the first one, should do somehting like:

```
background:url(../img/header/main_bg02.jpg) repeat top center;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

How could this be done?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple backgrounds on the same element (adjust sizes to your needs):

```
background: 
   url(bg1.png) 500px 100px no-repeat,
   url(bg2.png) 50px 100px repeat;
```

Comment: Good solution but IE8 doesn't support multiple backgrounds